# Problem with buildozer How can I correct this?

Tags: kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have a problem with buildozer.
Every time I use the comand "buildozer android debug" and installing the apk file on my smartphone, it just shows the start screen of the app and than it crashes.

buildozer.spec file:

[Link to buildozer.spec file](https://github.com/tct123/example-buildozer.spec/blob/main/buildozer.spec)

If I run the application on my Computer, it works.
On my Computer I run Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64 Bit.
I downgraded buildozer from dev version to 1.3.0.

Thanks for helping.

Here is my log file: https://github.com/tct123/example-buildozer.spec/blob/main/my_log.txt

Comment: Try connecting your Android phone to your computer, then run: `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt` and have a look at the `my_log.txt` file. See the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application).

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.